# How to edit dynamically generated datatable and datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datatable

So i have a form that looks like this:

[image]

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmQjN.png)

and I generate the datatable for the dataviewgrid in the load function:

```
private void loadEmpresas(){
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(gVariables.myConnection);
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select codempresa as 'Codigo', nomempresa as 'Nombre empresa' from contabilidad.empresas", myConn);

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = command;
        DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdataset);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

        bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        sda.Update(dbdataset);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

the table in mysql looks like this:

[image]

[SQL Table Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1eUJ.png)

so when it is running it shows this:

[image]

Now the problems that i have are that i have no idea how to modify the width of the columns, id like the entire table to cover that gray space and i want that on click it selects the entire row not just a cell. When it clicks the row i want to pupulate the rest of the textboxes but i have a problem with the click event which for testing purposes is this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("clicked");

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];    
        MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());                                
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("wat");
    }                    
}
```

when I click it doesn't even show a messagebox sometimes, I seriously have no idea how to handle the click row event properly :C help please T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating the column widths try using DataGridViewColumn.width:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

[DataGridViewColumn.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) property information.

To select the entire row you need to change the SelectionMode of the DataGrid to FullRowSelect:

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

[SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86(v=vs.110).aspx) information.